# for loop inside array terminating on second call

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, console-application

i have done coding in C# but not much inside the Console App (teacher is making us do an assignment in it)

I have a problem where my static method works fine the first time it is called (each question is asked), but the second time through the console closes. I need this function to execute 10 times and not sure why it wont. Here is what i have and thanks in advance!:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Lab2
{
    class Program
    {
        //Create the arrays
        static string[] questions = new string[5];  //For questions
        static int[] tableHeader = new int[10];      //Table Header
        static int[,] responses = new int[5, 10];   //For answers

        //Int for the number of times the questions have been asked
        static int quizCount = 0;
        static int answer;
        static bool isGoing = true;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Set the questions in an array
            questions[0] = "On a scale of 1-10, how do you feel about the drinking age in Wisconsin?";
            questions[1] = "On a scale of 1-10, how often do you drink a week?";
            questions[2] = "On a scale of 1-10, how important is this class?";
            questions[3] = "On a scale of 1-10, how would you rate this campus?";
            questions[4] = "On a scale of 1-10, how would you rate this command prompt?";
            while(isGoing)
                Questions();
        }

        static void Questions()
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(questions[i]);
                answer = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
                responses[i, quizCount] = answer;
            }
            if (quizCount < 10)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter more data? (1=yes, 0=no)");
                int again = Console.Read();
                if (again != 1)
                    Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else
                isGoing = false;
                DisplayResults();
        }

        static void DisplayResults()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tableHeader);
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
                {
                    Console.Write(responses[i, x]);
                }
                Console.Write("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check your logic? isGoing is set to false in the method Questions(). So as soon as it is false, the while loop stops. Thus your app displays and closes. If you want to console window to stay there then use Console.ReadKey() at the end of main method.

Comment: @zenwalker: You might have not looked close enough - `isGoing` is only set to false in an else clause that should not be executed  unless `quizCount` >= 10

Comment: Step through the line `int again = Console.Read();` in a debugger, look at the value of `again` and the problem should be obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off [Console.Read()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read.aspx) returns an int representing the ascii value of what was entered. If the user enters `1`, `Console.Read()` returns 49. (See this [ascii table](http://www.ascii.cl/))

You could use [Console.ReadKey()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx)

---

Second, you need some fixes in the way you loop and ask to continue....

Comment: Thanks! I have never heard of the ascii table or the difference between read and readline. I appreciate your help!

Comment: :) You're welcome. Always consult msdn. See the [methods of the console class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz3fhfz1.aspx) Read up on ascii/unicode also, it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

```
int again = Console.Read();
```

Your problem is here - `Console.Read()` returns the first *character* entered (as represented by its ASCII code), not the number you type in. I leave the solution for your homework.

Comment: Thank You! That was the problem!